# Find the maximum element by summing overlapping intervals

Tags: python, sorting, max, intervals, overlapping

Say we are given the total size of the interval space. Say we are also given an array of tuples giving us the start and end indices of the interval to sum over along with a value. After completing all the sums, we would like to return the maximum element. How would I go about solving this efficiently?

Input format: n = interval space, intervals = array of tuples that contain start index, end index, and value to add to each element

```
    Eg: 
    Input: n = 5, intervals = [(1,2,100),(2,5,100),(3,4,100)]
    Output: 200
    
    so array is initially [0,0,0,0,0]
    
    At each iteration the following modifications will be made:
    1) [100,100,0,0,0]
    2) [100,200,100,100,100]
    3) [100,200,200,200,100]
    
    Thus the answer is 200.
```

All I've figured out so far is the brute force solution of splicing the array and adding a value to the spliced portion. How can I do better? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: edited to add format

Comment: Is intervals fixed to only 3?

Comment: can be greater than 3

Comment: So how can we figure out the number of intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to separate your intervals into a beginning and an end, and specify how much is added or subtracted to the total based on whether you are in that interval or not.  Once you sort the intervals based on their location on the number line, you traverse it, adding or subtracting the values based on whether you enter or leave the interval.  Here is some code to do so:

```
def find_max_val(intervals):
  operations = []
  for i in intervals:
    operations.append([i[0],i[2]])
    operations.append([i[1]+1,-i[2]])
  unique_ops = defaultdict(int)
  for operation in operations:
    unique_ops[operation[0]] += operation[1]

  sorted_keys = sorted(unique_ops.keys())

  print(unique_ops)
  curr_val = unique_ops[sorted_keys[0]]
  max_val = curr_val
  for key in sorted_keys[1:]:
    curr_val += unique_ops[key]
    max_val = max(max_val, curr_val)

  return max_val


intervals = [(1,2,100),(2,5,100),(3,4,100)]

print(find_max_val(intervals))
# Output: 200
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this was exactly what I was looking for. The runtime looks to be nlog(n) which is better than the nested for loops I had going.

Comment: Hey I realized it wasn't quite right in case an addition and a subtraction came at the same point, so I added a loop where I combine transitions so that there can only be one addition or subtraction per point.  I edited my post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for 3 intervals.

```
n = int(input())
x = [0]*n
interval = []
for i in range(3):
   s = int(input()) #start
   e = int(input()) #end
   v = int(input()) #value
   #add value
   for i in range (s-1, e):
      x[i] += v
  
print(max(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to do a lot of the work.

```
n=5
intervals = [(1,2,100),(2,5,100),(3,4,100)]

intlst = [[r[2] if i>=r[0]-1 and i<=r[1]-1 else 0 for i in range(n)] for r in intervals]

lst = [0]*n  #[0,0,0,0,0]
for ls in intlst:
  lst = [lst[i]+ls[i] for i in range(n)]

print(lst)
print(max(lst))
```

Output

```
[100, 200, 200, 200, 100]
200
```